# Simple way to center images with equal margin

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to center seven images in a Bootstrap 3 container (red in the image), until the images don't fit next to each other anymore. Now I could hardcode the width of the container and measure the margins and apply that separately for every image and for every screen size etc. or via JavaScript (jQuery).

Is there an easy way to get the following result which also works when the container size changes?

```
<footer>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="social">
            <img src="img/social/twitter.png" />
            <img src="img/social/twitter.png" />
            <img src="img/social/twitter.png" />
            <img src="img/social/twitter.png" />
            <img src="img/social/twitter.png" />
            <img src="img/social/twitter.png" />
            <img src="img/social/twitter.png" />
        </div>
    </div>
</footer>
```

**How it is:**
[image: Now]

**How it should be:**
[image: Should be]

Comment: Please add some code to your answer, showing us what you tried to do.

Comment: You can either put the images inside another container and center that OR you can use 14% width (=100/7) for the images.

Comment: @OlivierH Added some code, although I'm afraid that won't help anything.

Comment: @user2261073 That's not what I'm trying to accomplish. I want the most left images on the left and the most right image on the right and the images in between should have the same margin. I'll add an image of how it should be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Bootstrap-y approach would be to use `nav-justified`..

```
<div class="container">
  <ul class="social nav nav-justified">
    <li class="text-center"><img src="//placehold.it/75x75"></li>
    <li class="text-center"><img src="//placehold.it/75x75"></li>
    <li class="text-center"><img src="//placehold.it/75x75"></li>
    <li class="text-center"><img src="//placehold.it/75x75"></li>
    <li class="text-center"><img src="//placehold.it/75x75"></li>
    <li class="text-center"><img src="//placehold.it/75x75"></li>
    <li class="text-center"><img src="//placehold.it/75x75"></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

http://bootply.com/94870

But I'm not sure what you want to happen when "the images don't fit next to each other anymore"?

Comment: I meant when the screen gets smaller, but this is indeed the right answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

use

```
text-align: justify;
```

on the parent container in order to evenly space all the images like in your example.

For further reading: http://css-tricks.com/grids-with-text-align-justify/